# Can I create a constraint to a subset of data?

Tags: sql-server, constraint

Here's a simplified view of my database

```
|---------------|     |-----------|
| ORGANIZATION  |     | CONTACT   |
|---------------|     |-----------|
| OrgId         |     | ContactId |
| OrgName       |     | OrgId     |
| MainContactId |     | FullName  |
|---------------|     |-----------|
```

Is there a way to ensure that `MainContactId` only belongs to the subset of the `CONTACT` table where the `OrgId` matches?

I did some looking and found that I can use a user defined function, but that appears to have performance issues. Do I have any other options here?

EDIT:
I played around, and got the following working. Is there a problem with this approach?

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckOrgMainContact(@OrgId int, @ContactId int)
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Result int

        IF @ContactId IS NULL --if the contact ID is not set, don't check it
        BEGIN
           SET @Result = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                       FROM dbo.Contact
                       WHERE OrgId = @OrgId and 
                             ContactId = @ContactId)
               SET @Result = 1
            ELSE
               SET @Result = 0
        END
        RETURN @Result
    END
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Organization
    (
       OrgId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
       OrgName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       MainContactId int NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [CheckOrgMainContact_Constraint] CHECK (dbo.CheckOrgMainContact(OrgId, MainContactId)=1)
    )
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Contact
    (
       ContactId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
       OrgId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Organization(OrgId),
       FullName varchar(50) NOT NULL
    )  
    GO
    ALTER TABLE Organization 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MainContact FOREIGN KEY (MainContactId) 
        REFERENCES dbo.Contact (ContactId) 
    GO

    --let's get some date inot the tables
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Organization ON
    INSERT INTO Organization (OrgId, OrgName)
    VALUES(1, 'Google'),
          (2, 'Microsoft'),
          (3, 'Leidos');
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Organization OFF

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Contact ON
    INSERT INTO Contact (ContactId, OrgId, FullName)
    VALUES (1, 1, 'Homer'),
           (2, 1, 'Marge'),
           (3, 1, 'Bart'),
           (4, 2, 'Bob'),
           (5, 2, 'Linda'),
           (6, 2, 'Gene'),
           (7, 3, 'Frank'),
           (8, 3, 'Dee'),
           (9, 3, 'Dennis')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Contact OFF


    UPDATE Organization SET MainContactId = 1 WHERE OrgName = 'Google' --set this to a valid contact

    UPDATE Organization SET MainContactId = 4 WHERE OrgName = 'Google' --try setting this to an invalid contact


    SELECT o.OrgName, c.FullName FROM Organization o INNER JOIN Contact c on o.OrgId = c.OrgId --get all the contacts
    SELECT o.OrgName, c.FullName as MainContact FROM Organization o LEFT JOIN Contact c ON o.MainContactId = c.ContactId
```

Comment: You mean like a Foreign Key?

Comment: Please include the rdbms platform you're on in the tags.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, yes, but I have to make sure that the MainContactID only comes from the contacts for that org

Comment: Your problem seems similar - if not identical - to this question: [How to have a one-to-many relationship with a privileged child?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/how-to-have-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-a-privileged-child)