# Circular dependency in schema or boolean with CHECK?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
create table repositories (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table remotes (
    id serial primary key,
    url varchar(255) unique not null,
    repository_id integer references repositories(id) not null
);
```

I want to have an "origin" remote for a repository.

I have 2 solutions:

- Create a circular dependency, which means using `ALTER TABLE` in the schema:

  ```
  alter table repositories add origin_remote_id integer references remotes(id);
  ```
- Add a flag on `remotes` with a custom `CHECK` constraint:

  ```
  create table remotes (
      id serial primary key,
      url varchar(255) unique not null,
      repository_id integer references repositories(id) not null,
      is_origin boolean not null constraint is_only_origin check (is_only_origin(repository_id))
  );
  ```

The problem is that the 1st approach makes relationally more sense, but it also introduces a circular dependency.

Is it fine? I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Check this: [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021) (the answer by Erwin) and the answers here: [How to have a one-to-many relationship with a privileged child?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/how-to-have-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-a-privileged-child) - but keep in mind that they are for SQL Server, which has not deferrable foreign key constraints - so the circular dependency is really unadvisable there.

Comment: If your question is similar to the questions above (i.e. you a repository has many remotes but only one of them is declared the "origin"), then the `repositories -> remotes` FK in the 1st solution is wrong, it should include two columns.

Comment: @ypercube thanks a lot! The other questions are exactly what I was looking for. And indeed, the 1st solution is wrong.

Comment: The 2nd is also not complete. You need a partial index to ensure that only one of the remotes has `is_origin` set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Having the `origin_remote` column in the `repositories` table allows for an intrinsic consistency, even without `check`, and you'll keep this consistency when changing DBMS and, more importantly, in the application code.

This also allows for a single query when you want to change the origin of a repository, while having your `is_origin` boolean would imply two queries which would have to be wrapped in a transaction.

In this specific case I'm of the opinion you should really use the standard relational link from `repositories` to `origin_remote_id`. The need to use `alter table` is just as a minor inconvenience.

Comment: How do you ensure in this case that the origin is really just an origin?  To me it looks like you have to pay this price somewhere.

Comment: @dezso As I understand the question, the origin is just the remote that is chosen as origin. But OP should confirm|infirm

Comment: @dezso I confirm what dystroy said. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: The current create table scripts (1st solution) allow for a repository to have a remote origin that is related to a different repository. I don't think this is wanted.