# one to many design struggle

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE fiber (
 fib_id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
 fib_number not null,
 fib_object uuid not null reference cable, --useless here but imagine a cable
 fib_optr uuid reference optical_road on delete set null,
 fib_color text not null
);

-- optical road are multiple fiber, spliced together. 
-- Onces spliced, it is just one long fiber. 

CREATE TABLE optical_road (
 optr_id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
 optr_name text not null,
 optr_client uuid reference client -- just an example
);
```

I want to enforce the fact that you cannot delete a fiber if it is linked to an optical road. I cannot find a design without trigger.

Imagine this record :

```
 fib_id   | fib_number | fib_object | fib_optr | fib_color 
 <anuuid> |          1 | <anuuid2>  | <anuuid3>| #12345
```

Then here I want that `DELETE FROM fiber where fib_id=<anuuid>` raises an error.

Comment: imagine this record :

    fib_id | fib_number | fib_object | fib_optr | fib_color
    <anuuid> | 1 | <anuuid2> | <anuuid3> | #12345

Then here I want that
DELETE FROM fiber where fib_id=<anuuid> raise an error

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent a child record (`fiber`) from being deleted if it has a parent (`optical_road`). Since the foreign key is not nullable, then by definition all records in `fiber` have parents in `optical_road`, so none can be deleted according to your logic, which can only be prevented by not granting the `delete` privilege.

Comment: Read this post it appears to be a similar requirement. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127107/implementation-of-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-total-participation-constrain

Answer (score 2):

```
optical_road {OPTR_ID, OPTR_NAME, OPTR_CLIENT}
          PK {OPTR_ID}


fiber {FIB_ID, FIB_NUMBER, FIB_OBJECT, FIB_COLOR}
   PK {FIB_ID}



fiber_road {FIB_ID, OPTR_ID}
        PK {FIB_ID}

       FK1 {FIB_ID}  REFERENCES fiber {FIB_ID} 
                     ON DELETE RESTRICT

       FK2 {OPTR_ID} REFERENCES optical_road {OPTR_ID} 
                     ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Note:

```
PK  = PRIMARY KEY
AKn = ALTERNATE KEY (UNIQUE)
FKn = FOREIGN KEY
```

Comment: OK, so you're implementation looks good to expect that the PK of `fiber_road` will be FIB_ID, OPTR_ID and fib_id will be unique.