# How to design a database with rare multiple values

Tags: database-design, design-pattern

I have a "user" table, with many attributes including "nationality".
the user can have multiple nationalities, so it sounds as if I have to design a new table to store this multiple value.

but what if I stored the first nationality in "user" table, and each of the remaining nationalities belonging to the same user would go to the nationality table.

I am thinking about this solution since it's pretty rare to have a user with multiple nationalities.. so, I can keep my design clean this way.

Is this feasible? is it a bad design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a one-to-many relationship with a privileged child?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/how-to-have-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-a-privileged-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me who doing the design what I will do is create a `table` with name `nationality` each nationality have `ID`  ...and since the the user have multiple nationality ...in the `user` table I will create two columns (`foreign key`) for nationality `nationality1` and `nationality2` referencing the `nationality` table .

the above scenario in case for **two nationality** .

**for multiple nationality (unlimited) check the below scenario**

the scenario for this situation will be similar to Customer and orders (one-to-many) ...one customers have many orders ...you will need 3 tables `user` `nationality` `user_nationality` in the `user_nationality` table you will the following columns `id`,`user_id`,`nationality_id` ...the `user_id` is `foreign key` column referencing the `user_id` in the `user` table and the `nationality_id` is a `foreign key` referencing `nationality_id` for the `nationality` table .

hope that will help .

Comment: But what if one user have more than two nationalities.. there is no restriction on the maximum number of nationalities a user can have.

Also it sounds like the nationality2 in your design would remain null most of the time, and I don't see it deserving to affect my table shecma in this fashion.

Comment: @AliSmart I have edited the answer and added a scenario for unlimited nationality ...basically it's similar to the scenario for one customer can have many orders ...(one-to-many) .

Comment: @AliSmart thanks ...all the best to you...yes you are right in your case it's many-to-many