# Circular references for tracking currently active entity

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I want to store active entity in one of my tables let's say I have 2 tables:

- Pirate
- Ship

*Named it like that to keep things interesting*

I want each pirate to own many ships but have only one active ship. For that `Ship will have PirateId` column and `Pirate will have ActiveShipId`. Obviously for that to work one of those columns has to be NULLable depending on the order I insert new entries.

I also have `IsActive` column on the Ship table, `ActiveShipId` is supposed to be a shortcut and will possibly give me better performance - Lets suppose I want to get active ship without circular reference:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Ship WHERE PirateId = @0 AND IsActive = 1
```

With circular references:

```
SELECT * FROM Ship WHERE Id IN (SELECT ActiveShipId FROM Pirate WHERE Id = @0)
```

[image: schema]

- Will this kind of circular reference cause me any problems?
- Is there any better way to design this schema?
- Is ActiveShipId redundant when I have IsActive, or will it provide any performance benefits?

Comment: Similar question: [How to have a one-to-many relationship with a privileged child?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/how-to-have-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-a-privileged-child)

Comment: And another, at SO, for Postgres this time. Erwin's answer explains how this can be accomplished, even with all columns NOT NULL: [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to find it and what terms to look for.

Comment: You can make the foreign key deferrable, then you can define `activeshipid` as not null and still insert both rows in a single transaction

Comment: You can even make it work with non-deferrable FKs, using modifying CTEs, inserting into both tables in one statement.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ sounds like something complicated to accomplish

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486 and the accepted answer

Comment: @EvanCarroll but it's not image of code, it's image of schema.

Comment: @LoneWolfMcQuade the image of the schema is ok, as a supplement. Much better if you posted the `CREATE TABLE` statements as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveShipId` isn't neccesary, because you already have an indicator at `Ship` table that says if the Ship is active or not. Assuming that a `Pirate` could own more than one `Ship`, and a `Ship` belongs only to a `Pirate`, then the you're modelling correctly (except the `ActiveShipId` workaround, it needs to be removed).

Also, by applying that workaround, you're ensuring that a Ship could belong to multiple Pirates. However, in case this not fit your needs, then give us more information about your modelling requirements.