# Best Method for Modeling/Implementing Dependent Primary Child?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, ms-access

I’ve implemented Primary Child functionality using a third table as described by @ypercube [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/how-to-have-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-a-privileged-child) (and other posts). I chose this method because it’s database-agnostic, simple (no triggers or deferred constraints), and seems clean. Here’s my table structure:

[image]

I’m trying to implement two business rules with this structure. The first seems to work, but not the second.

**Business Rule 1:** PrimaryChild must be a Usable Child, denoted by the boolean field Usable in the Child table.

To achieve this, I added a Usable field to PrimaryChild and composite keys in Child and PrimaryChild composed of ChildID + ParentID + Usable. Here’s the structure:

[image]

I then placed a Check constraint on the Usable field in PrimaryChild so that it must be TRUE. This seems to work well.

**Business Rule 2:** Usable status depends on other state fields in Child: ControlsUsable1, ControlsUsable2, etc. (four ControlsUsable’s now, more may come).

This suggests the Usable field on Child should be calculated, and calculated fields apparently can’t be used in composite foreign keys. I can think of only one potential solution: nix the derived Usable value and use each of the ControlsUsable fields instead. But I’d rather not because it complicates current and future query logic and means the composite foreign key (that seems to be necessary to achieve Business Rule 1) will consist of at least 6 fields in both Child and PrimaryChild.

Can you suggest a better solution? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you make `Usable` in Child table not a calculated column but a normal one and add a constraint, something like `CHECK (Usable = ControlsUsable1 OR ControlsUsable2 OR ...)`, whatever the business rule is ?

Comment: The disadvantage against a calculated column is that every insert and update (of ControlsUsable  columns) of the Child table would have to pass the correct value for Usable, too.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Boom Baby! Thank you! Just the guidance I needed.  Regarding the calculated column, it seems to me the inverse is true (I have three months of database experience, please forgive my ignorance): that an _advantage_ to a calculated column is upsert-ease because `Usable` would be derived from the `ControlsUsable` values we feed the table, simplifying data prep. And inversely, that constraining `Usable` will require upserts to include values for `Usable` and `ControlsUsable`…which complicates data prep. Do I have this bassackwards?